# Cannot Find Javax.Comm.Properties in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have developed an application which results serial ports in combobox, but when I am running `.jar` file of my application using command terminal using command:

```
Java -jar Serial_Send.jar    //where Serial_Send is name of my jar file
```

It is resulting into an error `Cannot find javax.comm.properties`.
But `javax.comm.properties` file is present in `java_home/jre/lib` directory.

What else I have to do in order to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
java -jar -Djava.class.path=java_home/jre/lib Serial_Send.jar
```

This will  put the `lib` directory in class path of program explicitly.